# close terminal by exit command on Centos6.7

Tags: terminal, centos, gnome

Im using Centos 6.7 and I want to close terminal window when there are no more subshells to logout.
If I open Gnome terminal and type "exit", it just prints "exit" instead of close the terminal window.
please help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFz29.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could see that behavior if you had run a subshell, e.g., typing `sh` or `bash` before.  You can see the shells (and their parent process-ids) using

```
ps -ef |grep bash | grep -v grep
```

For each level of the shell which you have run, you should **exit** that level.  Or you could make it quick:

```
pkill -9 bash
```

but if you are running as **root** (implied by the **`#`** prompt), that has bad side-effects (killing other processes than your own chain of subshells).